# Request method 'POST' not supported - spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I tried to *POST* like this : `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"fisrtName\":\"sunny\" ,  \"lastName\":\"leone\" }" http://localhost:8080/user`

But I get this error : *{"timestamp":"2019-12-06T11:07:17.196+0000","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/user"}*

But, I have my rest-controller like this :

```
@PostMapping("/user/{firstName}/{lastName}")
    User addUser(@PathVariable String firstName,@PathVariable String lastName)
    {
        return userRepository.save(new User(firstName,lastName));
    }
```

**How this can be resolved ?**

Comment: Well, look at your PostMapping. What is the path? Is it `/user` as you're using in your curl request? Does the method expects a JSON request body as you're sending in your curl request?

Comment: I'd recommend using a tool such as Postman for using REST url's, makes it a bit easier to understand if you're starting out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the firstName and the lastName as JSON.

But your mapping says that they are path variables:

```
@PostMapping("/user/{firstName}/{lastName}")
```

Now you try to access http://localhost:8080/user but there is no mapping for this path.

Your post mapping should be:

```
@PostMapping("/user")
User addUser(@RequestBody User user){
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.
if you use @RequestBody instead of pathvariable it will help.

```
@PostMapping("/user)
    User addUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        if(user==null){
        return null;
        }else
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

```
curl --location --request POST "http://localhost:8080/user" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data "{
  \"fisrtName\": \"sunny\",
  \"lastName\": \"leone\"
}"
```